# how to remove Index action from Homecontroller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

i've all the defaults in my Home controller as well as in routeconfig.cs.

I'm trying the following :

```
abc:111/ --> runs Index() method  
abc:111/Home --? runs Index() method  
abc:111/Home/Index --? runs Index() method  
abc:111/Home/Index/One --? runs Index() method  
abc:111/Home/One --? error
```

I'd like to execute home/one through my Index() method

Comment: So, what you want is that every Home/foo that does not exists, redirect to Home/Index instead?

Comment: That can be a solution, but i'd like the Home/One should execute the Index method directly. Is there anything i need to change in the routing table?

Answer (score 0):

See this:
     [asp-net-mvc-routing-overview](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)

Comment: thanx, but i did not find my answer in that article.

Comment: sry, still cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest solution would be

```
public ActionResult One(int id)
{
   return Index();
}
```

Comment: That can be, but "One" is a parameter. I will not be able to determine what will be the parameter at run time.                                                               I added one more route to my route table, "Home/{id}",
            new { Controller = "Home", Action = "Index", id=""}

Comment: You want Home/One to be routed to Home/Index/One ?

Comment: yeh, that can be a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can have a route mapped like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
           "Name",
            "{controller}/{param}",
            new { action = "Index" }
        );
```

Now this would catch Home/Index too of course but you can fix that by having route constraints.